# Repairing 'burnt' solder points

Tags: pcb, soldering

I recently came across a pcb.
This is the picture of the aforementioned PCB.

[image: Picture of PC]

As you can see, some solder points seem burnt. The copper trace has been removed.

Does this mean the PCB is dead? If I solder the component on the solder points, will it work?

Maybe I should do prework, like remove pieces of solder with solder wick?

Comment: The answer for the three questions you asked is: maybe. There is no way to tell just from an image. If someone has reworked this PCB to this point it means that they had a hard time trying to fix it. Some hypotheses may be created from these inferences but.. nothing definitive, so.. maybe, maybe not..

Comment: Yuck,  If you can see the traces that went to the missing pads, then you could either scrap back the coating, expose the copper and solder to that... or trace back to another node and solder a wire from there.  If that is all that is wrong the pcb should be salvageable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This horrific butchering 'repair job' can be repaired with time and patience, assuming the reasonable skills are there. The person who did this can be immediately disqualified by virtue of the latter requirement.

Presumably the part removed is known- maybe a SIP audio amplifier IC or a switch. The part needs to be replaced with a good one (hopefully that's all that is wrong). The pads are all lifted, including the ones that were for primarily mechanical reasons. For the latter perhaps epoxy to provide the mechanical support, but that  can wait until it is working.

First, clean the board with a mild solvent such as 99% isopropanol and one of those manual toothbrushes that the dentists give you at every visit (obviously it should be new, clean and not used for teeth afterward). Then inspect the damage.

I would run a thin (eg. AWG30-AWG24) insulated wire back to the nearest pad that used to be connected to those missing pads- follow the traces to where they went. This is a single-side paper-based phenolic board, so all the circuit is visible. The pads are also very weakly attached to the substrate. Make absolutely sure you get the connections to the right place- a mistake at this point could greatly compound the disaster. You can see that some traces  are peeled back by the ham-fisted thug that worked on it.

[image]

Use a sharp Xacto knife or similar fine blade to trim off the loose ends of the ripped traces so they can't get into trouble.

Make sure that the big pins or tabs are connected to the proper places in the same way  (with wires) as the copper around those pads is missing or compromised  (lifted). Looks like they were connected together and to a ground (?) pour via a thermal relief(s).

If you get the device working, make sure you provide mechanical support with something like epoxy.

Some of the unrelated component leads look a bit like cold solder joints, it might not hurt to carefully touch them up. If the device was intermittent that might have been the root cause.

Comment: +1 for both the excellent repair suggestions ** AND ** for mentioning that there may be bad solder joints on some of the SMD components.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to restore it, given the following

- you know what part was originally in. Initially I thought it is some transformer, but most probably it is some IC on the heat sink because both big pads were connected to ground. I might be wrong with it though :)
- Metallization of one of mounting holes is not yet damaged, another one is severely damaged but you will be able to fix connection by soldering a thick pin you usually cut off the through-hole resistors and capacitors when soldering them.
- pin pads are really damaged, thus your task here is to clean everything using spirit of other dissolvent. I do not think you will be able to restore tracks up to good contact with existing copper. You will need to ensure assembly you insert is well fixed through big holes, and then just use air-wires with decent isolation routing to nearest pads. It is very important to know temperature mode of the component you solder to with wires, if it will heat much wire may just disconnect and cause damage to device or even fire.

P.S. For me it seems to be single layer PCB. Device is probably TV, monitor, or some other low-integrated one.

Answer (score 1):

That PCB has been butchered during the removal of what looks like the switch-mode power supply transformer. The visible traces have been stripped and probably the through-hole plating and other side too.

Repair will be time-consuming, difficult and will require an identical transformer.

Recommendation: send for recycling.

Comment: This seems to be a one-layer PCB, there is no through-hole plating.

Comment: Looks more like a power amplifier IC on a heat sink tbh. A transformer would have a corresponding row of pins somewhere close.  The SO-8 looks kinda like it says 4560 which is an audio opamp. Not that it matters much.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if this happens your only choice is to repair the pads (which can be a painstaking process) or you can solder jumper wires to the nearest pads that used to be connected to the pads that are now removed. There is a such thing as "BER", or "Beyond Economical Repair". You really need to ask yourself, is it worth the trouble? Obviously the final decision is up to you. You probably won't be able to reuse the old pad locations either way, though.

Answer (score 1):

The traces could be repaired. They make a pen that costs about 25 bucks it has low resistance silver conductor impregnated with an adhesive. It draws very fine lines. If you want to be fancy they even make a 30 dollar pen to put the green back on the board, Caig labs.

I'm not a salesman - just don't let people tell you you cant do something, you can.

Sorry for resurrecting an old post but I don't want people looking this up and thinking they have to throw something away that they really want to keep. Plus they gain another tool and another skill.

Comment: Hi and welcome to EESE. This looks like a good tip, but I can't work out if this is a cunning advertisement. If you are affiliated with the company in any way, then you should disclose that fact.